# Meaning of view: View

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

What is the meaning of `view: View` in Kotlin for Android?

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Is this a serious question? I'd start reading the documentation first

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is the parameters to pass into the function : `view:View`. It says you pass in a parameter of type `View` and when you use it in the function you reference it by it's name `view`.

For example:

```
fun doubleNumber(num:Int) : Int{
   return num * num
}
```

In this function `doubleNumber` we pass in a parameter of type `Int` and call it `num`. You can see that within the function when we want to use that passed in parameter we use it's name `num`.

Comment: thankyou , but i knew this .... SOMEBODY EDITED MY QUESTION .. actually i want to ask that how a view can be a datatype ? number , string is a datatype but a view ? means

Comment: It's a class called View. You should look it up in the documentation.